# How could I show that $\mathbb{E}_{Y}[Y] = \mathbb{E}_{X} [\mathbb{E}_{Y}(Y | X)]$ when X and Y are continuous random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> How could I show that $\mathbb{E}_{Y}[Y] = \mathbb{E}_{X} [\mathbb{E}_{Y}(Y | X)]$ when X and Y are continuous random variables?

I've seen how to do it for discrete random variables however I'm not sure how to prove it in the continuous case, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Do you know anything about measure theory? This so-called "tower property" is nearly the defining property of conditional expectation in the measure-theoretic framework.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does the subscript notation mean? Wikipedia doesn't appear to use it...

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Good point, this is a terrible notation, completely useless, which for some unknown reasons seems to survive in some curricula.

Comment: @Ian Ohh I don't think I do to be honest, maybe a minimal amount but I haven't properly studied the subject, the tower property is also new to me

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353418/expected-value-proof-law-of-total-expectation

Comment: A part of the definition of the random variable $Z=E(Y\mid X)$ is that $E(Z\mathbf 1_A)=E(Y\mathbf 1_A)$ for every $A$ in the sigma algebra $\sigma(X)=\{X^{-1}(B);B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}$ generated by $X$. Since $\Omega=X^{-1}(\mathbb R)$ belongs to $\sigma(X)$, one gets $E(Z)=E(Y)$, qed.

Comment: @Did If you say so. I wasn't trying to make a statement; I really don't know what it means.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein from what I know, the notation means that that expectation considers probabilities of the subscripted variable in the expectation, e.g. $E_Y[X] =$ sum of products $xp(Y = y)$  or for example $E_X[X] =$ sum of products $xp(X = x)$

Comment: @silverjoe Thanks! So what's inside the brackets needs to be a function of the subscript. That makes sense.

Comment: @silverjoe When you start dealing with conditional expectation when the conditional variable is continuous, and you don't use the measure-theoretic framework, the technicalities start getting tricky. For example, if $X$ is normally distributed, $E[X \mid X^2]$ is discrete even though $X$ and $X^2$ are both continuous.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein That's alright no prob!

Comment: @Ian I see, I see, it looks kind of tricky